# CSS - Metodología BEM e hijos

Tags: css, bem

soy nuevo con la metodología BEM para CSS, y tengo una duda respecto a los hijos de un modificador.

Digamos que tengo este HTML:

```
<div class="block-container">
    <div class="block-container__element"></div>
</div>
```

Al `block-container` le añado el modificador `block-container--modifier`.

El CSS se vería de la siguiente manera:

```
.block-container {
    ...
}
.block-container__element {
    ...
}
.block-container--modifier {
    ...
}
```

Y esta es mi pregunta: ¿cómo puedo cambiar algunos atributos CSS de  `__element` cuando añado el modificador?

He leído, que debemos evitar hacer "nesting" (que nada dependa de un padre), pero supongo que en algunas ocasiones, como esta, esa regla o sugerencia debe romperse para lograr cambiar algunos estilos, ¿verdad?

Uso CSS puro, ningún pre-procesador como SASS o LESS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si necesitas modificar atributos a `.block__element`, simplemente crea una clase la cual utilice selector descendiente para el mismo, es decir, `.block--modifier .bock__element`.

#### Ejemplo

```
.bock--mod .bock__element {
  /* stuff */
}
```

Fuente: [Can a block modifier affect elements?](http://getbem.com/faq/#block-modifier-affects-elements)

> Al crear el selector anidado, declara que una entidad depende de otra. Debido a que `BEM` introduce componentes independientes, **este enfoque no se sugiere cuando estamos hablando de 2 bloques diferentes**.
>
> Pero **cuando se trata de un bloque y su elemento, no tienen un significado equivalente**. Por definición, un elemento no tiene ningún sentido fuera de su bloque principal. Entonces, un elemento es una entidad dependiente de bloques. Suponiendo esto, **es bastante normal y lógico que un elemento se vea afectado por el estado actual del bloque**.

Comment: Vale si, es como lo estaba realizando. ¡Gracias!